# Display a NEW tag/icon on a 1 week old WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show an icon/text on new posts which are of 1 week old but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? I have been searching for a tutorial but couldn't find any either except this which shows for `-2 years`. I converted to `-1 week` which isn't working.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'whats-new',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
        $arr_posts->the_post();
        ?>
        <article>
              <div class="news">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                <?php 
                    if( strtotime( $post->post_date ) < strtotime('-1 week') ) {
                    echo '';
                    } else {
                    echo '<span class="icon icon-new">new posts';
                    }
                ?>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code looks good for retrieving posts with the category 'whats-new' and displaying them with a "NEW" icon for posts less than one week old. However, there are a couple of minor corrections you can make for better structure and readability. Also, the closing  tag seems to be unnecessary and might be a typo.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'category_name'  => 'whats-new',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$arr_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if ($arr_posts->have_posts()) :
    while ($arr_posts->have_posts()) :
        $arr_posts->the_post();
        ?>
        <article>
            <div class="news">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                <?php
                if (strtotime(get_the_date()) < strtotime('-1 week')) {
                    echo '';
                } else {
                    echo '<span class="icon icon-new">NEW</span>';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw, what changes should I make if I want to show it for say 10 days?

Comment: If you want to display the "NEW" tag for posts that are 10 days old or less, you can modify the comparison in the if statement accordingly. Here's the updated condition: 

From: if (strtotime(get_the_date()) < strtotime('-1 week')) {}
To: if (strtotime(get_the_date()) < strtotime('-10 days')) {}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy